# Cannot execute binary file error when running bibtex2html

Tags: linux, bibtex

I'm working on a project for a friend on a machine I'm not familiar with and I've run into some errors.

I'm running a program called bibtex2html, which is used to generate an HTML reference page. When I run the program, it gives me a "Cannot execute binary file" error.

From my preliminary research, it seems there are a number of causes to this problem, and I'm not really sure to begin.

What I've done so far:

```
uname -a -> 
Linux baseline 2.6.38-15-generic-pae #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 22 11:48:17 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

file ~/bibtex2html/bibtex2html -> ~/bibtex2html/bibtex2html: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did all the research correctly, now you just need to interpret it. It's a 64-bit executable (`x86-64`), and you're on a 32-bit kernel (`i686`). You'll need to find or compile a 32-bit version of bibtex2html.